# Favicon 404 with Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am getting a 404 on my `favicon.ico` file and not exactly sure the best way around it.

I am setting the favicon in my `HtmlWebpackPlugin` it gets the asset and outputs just fine.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: './index.html',
   favicon: 'favicon.ico',
   filename: '../index.html',
   chunks: ['runtime', 'index'],
   xhtml: true
}),
```

My output, isn't the default, it's path is to `target/webapp/app/`, this cannot be changed;

```
output: {
   publicPath: ASSET_PATH,
   filename: '[name].[hash].js',
   chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'target/webapp/app/')
},
```

I also use `CopyWebpackPlugin` to add the `favicon.ico` to the `target/webapp` which is where `index.html` gets output to.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
   { from: '../webapp/**/*', to: '../' },
   { from: 'fragments', to: '../fragments' },
   { from: 'favicon.ico', to: '../favicon.ico' },
]),
```

I also have the file loader of ico file, just in case

```
{
   test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
   exclude: /app\/og-images/,
   use: [
      'file-loader'
   ]
},
```

This is the structure of `target/webapp/` looks like;

```
+-- app
| +-- favicon.ico
| +-- index.js
| +-- index.css
| +-- runtime.js
+-- fragments
+-- index.html
+-- favicon.ico
```

In the compiled `index.html` file has the following;

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

But this gives me a 404.

However, if I manually edit the compiled `index.html` file to be

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./app/favicon.ico"/>
```

It works.

Hitting `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico` gives me a 404 but `http://localhost:8080/app/favicon.ico` works fine.

Comment: Have you tried setting your HtmlWebpackPlugin json to `favicon: './app/favicon.ico',` in your webpack config? Apologies if I misunderstood your implementation, but I ran into a similar error recently, and in my case, tracking it down to the webpack config sorted it out.

Comment: I had tried, I get `Error: HtmlWebpackPlugin: could not load file ....` for favicon